# bootstrap-datetimepicker enabledDates not working as expected

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

[bootstrap-datetimepicker](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker)

I am using this plugin and having issues in enabling certain dates.

This snippet correctly enables dates during initialization.

```
$("#example-datepicker").datetimepicker({
    locale: "en",
    format: 'M.D.YYYY',
    useCurrent: true,
    enabledDates: ['2020-07-24', '2020-08-25']
});
```

But after initialization, when I wanna update enabled dates, it doesn't work.

```
$("#example-datepicker").data("DateTimePicker").enabledDates(['2020-02-24', '2020-05-25']);
```

Any help is much appreciated!

PS: Are there any other plugins that can control what dates to enable?

Comment: It looks like it might be a conflict between the format you specified and the format used in the enabledDates array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `extraFormats` in initialization.

```
$("#example-datepicker").datetimepicker({
    locale: "en",
    format: 'M.D.YYYY',
    extraFormats: ['YYYY-MM-DD'],
    useCurrent: true,
    enabledDates: ['2020-07-24', '2020-08-25']
});
```

By adding that, the plugin can understand dates provided in `enabledDates`.
The reason it was rendered correctly at initialization is that since `YYYY-MM-DD` is a standard Date format, it is recognized.
But after initialization (`format` has been specified), it can no longer recognize the standard format.